# InputStream of socket not closing on peer loss

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, inputstream

I am connecting to an device with opening an socket.
To get incoming data I perform an `read`action on the `InputStream` in a different thread.
When I take away the electricity of the peer device I am connected to, my InputStream doesn't recognize the loss of connection.

This is my code to wait for input:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
String result = "";
int c;
try
{
  log.info( "waiting for data..." );
  while ( ( ( c = inputStream.read() ) >= 0 ) )
  {
    if ( c == -1 )
    {
      log.info( "is -1" );
    }
    /*
     * TODO: <LF> Can't always be the delimiter to define the end of an message. This should be
     * parameterized.
     */
    if ( c == 0x0a /* <LF> */ )
    {
      result = sb.toString();
      sb.delete( 0, sb.length() );
    }
    else if ( c != 0x0d /* <CR> */ )
    {
      sb.append( (char) c );
    }
    if ( !result.isEmpty() )
    {
      log.info( getName() + ": received message: " + result );
      listener.MessageReceived( result.getBytes() );
      result = "";
    }
  }
  log.info( "stream ended" );
  disconnect();
  listener.closed();
}
catch ( IOException | ResourceException e )
{
  try
  {
    log.info( "in catch block" );
    disconnect();
    listener.closed();
    throw new ResourceException( "An error occured during the receiving of a message for the device, or connection timed out.", e );
  }
  catch ( ResourceException e1 )
  {
    e1.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

This is inside of an JCA connector if that information is for use in any case.
To my knowledge the InputStream receives `-1` when the Stream is interrupted and normally he should jump to my `stream ended`log but it doesn't happen.

why doesn't it recognize that the connection can't be available, since the remote peer is powered off?

Comment: How long does it take before your code recognizes that the peer has been turned off?

Comment: not at all. I waited for about 10 minutes and he didn't recognize it. I didn't set an Timeout for the inputStream because I need to wait as long as the connection is established even if the peer doesn't send for hours.

Comment: So everything works as expected. There's no "help me I've lost connection" message that could be sent, so since you don't expect to get information, you have no idea whether the device is dead or it's just not sending data.

Comment: Not really @Kayaman.
I powered off the device I am connecting to. It is off. So the inputStream looses validity ( shouldn't it? ) so I want to catch that the peer is not available anymore and inform my listener about that.
EDIT: That's ok but I understood that the InputStream receives -1 when the peer is lost and I want to catch that if possible.

Comment: No, it shouldn't. If you ring my doorbell and I don't answer it, you don't know whether I'm in the shower, ignoring you or dead. Same deal applies here. You need to send a "heartbeat". That's when the write will fail. You've configured your read not to timeout, so it **will** wait forever until it gets something to read.

Comment: Damn so there is no workaround for constantly sending a check if the peer is alive. Alright so I will have to open another thread to constantly "ping" it every 20 seconds. Thanks!

Comment: Or you could use a read timeout and use the same thread for the heartbeat.

Comment: read timeout isn't a solution since I am connected to laboratory devices and such. they might not perform work over night but if my system still runs I need to keep that connection alive. Heartbeat is my solution to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A 'read timeout', as suggested by @Kayaman, IS the usual method of implementing a heartbeat. You need a 'timingOut' boolean, initialized to false.   Whenever ANY data is received, data or heartbeat poll reply, set it to false.  Upon read timeout check the 'timingOut' flag.  If false, send a poll request and set 'timingOut' to true.  If true, close socket and take your 'connection lost' action/s.

No need for a separate thread.  No wasteful polling if data is being transferred often.

Comment: Very nice way of handling this. I will give it a shot, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

As you say, you don't want a timeout because you need to wait for the peer even if it doesn't send for hours. Barring special measures, there is no difference between a peer that doesn't send for hours and a peer that has been turned off. As long as no packets are sent, it's impossible to detect the difference.

You can do one thing to ensure that packets are sent: you can turn on the SO_KEEPALIVE socket option using the method `Socket.setKeepAlive(true)`.

The problem is that you can't control from Java how often the keep-alive probes are sent. This typically depends on settings in your operating system kernel.
Still, it will allow you to detect a dead (or unreachable) peer quicker than "never".

Comment: Thank you for your and @Kayaman 's answers. I learned something today :) Will try out how fast KeepAlive will be, since it's kinda in a critical situation where I need to act as fast as possible.